# Write large byte arrays on RAID0 virtual disk

Tags: c#, .net-core, byte, console-application, raid

I have a camera that produces 20 frames per second.
I made an app in C# that grabs the frames and put them in a concurrent queue.
I have another thread that writes the frames on filesystem.
Each frame is an array of 134184960 bytes that I must write on filesystem.
The filesystem is an array of 20 SSD in RAID0 with theoretical speed of 500 MB/s * 20 with the bottleneck of PCiExpress 8x (7,7 GB/s)
The production rate is about 2,5 GB/s, but my writing speed doesn't go over 900 MB/s
I am using Filestream.Write ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/api/system.io.filestream.write?view=net-5.0))

What can I do to increase my writing speed?

```
private ConcurrentQueue<CapturedFrame> cq = new ConcurrentQueue<CapturedFrame>();

....

try
{
    while (cq.TryDequeue(out BufferToWrite))
    {
        byte[] bufferInBytes = new byte[134184960];

        //Matrox function to extract bytes
        MIL.MbufGetColor(BufferToWrite.IDFrame, MIL.M_PLANAR, MIL.M_ALL_BANDS, bufferInBytes);
    
        using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(AcquisitionFolder, DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd-HHmmss-fffffff") + ".raw"), FileMode.Create))
        {
            fileStream.Write(bufferInBytes, 0, bufferInBytes.Length);
            fileStream.Close();
        }
    }   
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    log.Error("Exception: " + ex.Message);
}
```

changed the FileStream to this with no improvement
65536 = 64K is the stripe size of the RAID0 array, I've set the lenght of the stream

```
using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(AcquisitionFolder, DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd-HHmmss-fffffff") + ".raw"), FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read, 65536, FileOptions.SequentialScan))
                    {
                        fileStream.SetLength(3 * 8192 * 5460);
                        fileStream.Write(bufferInBytes, 0, bufferInBytes.Length);
                        fileStream.Close();
                    }
```

Comment: .net 6 does support [`WriteFileGather()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-writefilegather) which allows you to supply several buffers at once to write - that might provide a small speed improvement, but I think it's very unlikely to make much difference.

Comment: I've found this paper (Sequential File Programming Patterns and Performance with .NET https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=52334) online with samples of code attached, but still cannot find a way to speed up my writing

Comment: Is your code running on the machine that hosts those disks. or are you connected through a gigabit network? Have you determined it's C#/.NET that's limiting the throughput? Have you considered playing with buffer sizes of the stream? And so on.

Comment: 1) My code is running on the machine that hosts the RAID0 array of disks
2) I am not sure if the problem is C# or else. I chose the RAID0 configuration expecting a much higher write speed. How can I determine if C# is the limiting factor?
3) I've already tried many Filestream buffers sizes with no big improvements

Comment: I've used a tool to test disk speed (http://www.roylongbottom.org.uk/diskgraf%20results.htm) and it gave me a speed of around 4 GB/s https://imgur.com/a/zBNFpil

Comment: File writing in C# is extremely fast, so I suspect there's some issues in your code. Difficult to say without seeing it. Some multithreading issue perhaps.

Comment: I've added part of my code
ConcurrentQueue that contains the frames
Each frame is an array of 134184960 bytes
A producer thread enqueues elements at a rate of 2,5 GB/S
Each element is added to a List of 

This is part of the consmer thread that writes to filesystem

Comment: This is my code before I started tweaking with the buffer and using P/Invoke CreateFile and handles

Comment: You're creating a separate file for each block - that's probably one thing that's slowing it down. Opening and closing a file has large overhead compared to writing sequentially. The other thing is: How many threads are simultaneously writing the files? Multiple threads writing files tends to slow things down rather than speeding things up.

Comment: I've tried to create one file for many (5 to 10) frames/blocks, but the improvement was very little. I've added the array of bytes to a List and when the List reached the limit i wrote the elements with FileStream.Write in a loop on the same file
There is only one consumer thread writing on the filesystem

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reach the 2,5 GB/s write speed with two steps:

- accessing the frames directly in memory, using byte* pointers
- writing the frames using Span structure and FileStream "unbuffered"
  as    described in the paper i linked before
  https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=52334